# Second <span> in JS not working "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')"

Tags: javascript, html

i wrote a JS code for my Website, which should show a modal and close it, if i click the "close" span. The first time, it worked perfectly. Here is the code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById("notifications");
var img = document.getElementById("shownotificationbar");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

But the second time, the close button just dont work and i get

"*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')*"

Here is the second code piece:

```
var menu = document.getElementById("startmenu");
var img = document.getElementById("showstartmenu");
var span = document.getElementById("closemenu");


img.onclick = function() {
  menu.style.display = "block"; 
}

span.onclick = function() {
  menu.style.display = "none";
}
```

I think i can't use two spans, but what else should i do?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, in the secon code piece i did not copyed the first line, i thinks its not important, but here it is: var menu = document.getElementById("startmenu");

Comment: You can edit the question, there is an edit link just below the tags

Comment: Use `<button>` for interactive buttons

Comment: Show the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Well, most of the time when JS says, `Can't set properties of null` it simply means that the element doesn't exist in the DOM. `null` means that the element is non-existent. Try checking if you can `console.log` the element you are applying `onclick` on. Make sure you are fetching the element with the correct `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second time `img` is null, so you cannot set `img.onclick`. The reason it is `null` is probably that there is no element with id `showstartmenu`, so when you are trying to get it (`document.getElementById("showstartmenu")`), you are getting `null` instead.

Edit:

Sorry, it could also be that `span` is null, for the same reason. I missed that one.

Comment: Okay, i think i got the principle. I solved it as @cloned wrote, by using a simple button instead. Perhaps its not the best way for learning JS, but it solved my problem for the moment. But thank you anyways!

Comment: That's fine, but for the benefit of the community (in case anyone searches "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null" in the future, and also so that people will know the issue has been resolved), you should still accept the answer, if that indeed was the problem.